# Recommended format of $id in JSON schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

We are trying to design JSON schema for our data using [jsonschema draft-07](https://json-schema.org/draft-07/json-schema-release-notes.html).

It's our first experience with JSON schema. We need to clarify what is preferred way to specify $id. The $id should be URI. We can see it's often URL. This URL not necessary exists, or is reachable, but should be unique. The other option is URN.

What we should consider to choose what would fit for us. Are there some advantages/disadvantages. What is a common or preferred option among users of JSON schema standard?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have done your research to understand the requirements for `$id`.

Usually, you will define a URL. A URL is more widley understood than a URN.

Unless you have any specific requirements to share, what you use does not really matter as long as it's consistent.

You can choose any URL you like, as long as when you use references, you use the same URL in your `$ref` reference.